# Get AppleScript's "do shell script" to use the latest Bash

Tags: applescript, bash

For some reason, I cannot get AppleScript's "do shell script" to use the latest (GPLv3) Bash:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/bash; echo $BASH_VERSION"
-- Result: "3.2.57(1)-release"
```

Strangely, it *does* work with an external .sh script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

Calling it like:

```
do shell script "~/Library/Scripts/Script.sh"
-- Result: "5.0.17(1)-release"
```

What's the difference and can I get it to work inside the .scpt script as well?

Comment: The first one doesn't issue the `echo $BASH_VERSION` in the sub shell you created.  Whereas the scripts have the she-bang that specifies exactly which shell to execute the code in.

Comment: @Allan I'm still not sure if my issue can be solved then. Can I get the subshell inside my .scpt file to use the latest Bash?

Comment: @abc I'm getting some errors but I don't think that works.

Comment: You should be able to, but remember, if you've changed your environment path, for the GUI, you probably need to log out/in for it to get the changes.  Confirm it by `do shell script "echo $PATH`" and see if it has the new values before logging out and then again after logging back in.

Comment: @Daan what errors are you getting?

Comment: @Allen See @abc's answer. The problem is that `do shell script` always uses `/bin/sh`. I have to use `-c` option and give the commands in a string.

Comment: @abc Some quoting-related errors, but the single quotes solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do shell script` always uses `/bin/sh`, even if your default shell, shebang, or `$PATH` variable is set to something else.

To force it to use a different shell, you will need to call that shell. To run a command in bash, use the argument `-c`:

```bsh
/usr/local/bin/bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'
```

If you only want to run a single bash script, you can omit the `-c` with: `/usr/local/bin/bash /path/to/script.bash`

---

In AppleScript:

```bsh
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'"
```

---

The man page entry for `bash -c`:

> `-c command_string`
>
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.

Comment: It's good to run `do shell script "set"` just by itself to see what's available by default when shelling out.

Comment: Thank you, that works. My confusion was caused by the fact that I see things like `do shell script "/bin/tcsh my-command-file-path"` (from an Apple doc), which made me think that it works the same for direct commands. Isn't the shell specifier redundant to begin with if you use a shebang in the external script file?

Comment: It will ignore the shebang because it will attempt to execute the script using `/bin/sh` instead of treating the script like an executable. If you want to run only a bash script (not a command) you can just use `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/bash /full/path/to/script.bash"`

Comment: Alright. But if my script is already an executable (which it needs to be) with the shebang I can just do something like `do shell script "~/Library/Scripts/Script.sh"` right? I'll probably go for that option.

Comment: For me it runs in the latest Bash with just the shebang; with Script Editor as well as FastScripts. I even did the reboot to make sure that it 'stuck'.

Comment: @Daan oh great! on my machine it still uses `/bin/sh`, weird

Comment: Yeah, odd. You're sure your script is executable? I've set it to `chmod u+x`.

Answer (score 0):

In your shell scripts, you should use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Why?

It will use the bash that you've specified in your $PATH because the `/bin/bash` may be entirely different than the bash in `/usr/local/bin/bash` that you installed after the fact.

To ensure that you "get" the correct bash version, make sure  that it's directory precedes the original in your path statement.  For instance, if it's located in `/opt/local/bin`, your path may look something like this:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: Thank you - useful to know. I've changed my scripts with this line. Indeed, I have the paths saved in `/etc/paths` with `/usr/local/bin` as the first line.